# Select collection by variable name: window[type] doesn't work

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, ecmascript-6

I need to keep the helpers dynamic to get a cursor. That means, the user can change the collection - by click event - which is used to get a list. 
But in my `console.log` I get a `undefined` for `window[type]`. What am I doing wrong?

So `article.find()` would work, but `window[type]` not...

**imports/api/example/index.js**

```
export const article = new Mongo.Collection('articles');
export const images = new Mongo.Collection('images');
```

**imports/api/example/client/example.js**

```
import { article, images } from '../';

Template.example.helpers({
    list() {
        const type = Template.instance().section.get();
        console.log(type, window[type]); // result: 'article', undefined
        return window[type].find(); // <- therefore this is NOT working
    }
});

Template.example.onCreated(function() {
    this.section = new ReactiveVar('article');
});

Template.example.events({
    'click .target': function(event, template) {
        const   $this = $(event.currentTarget),
                type  = $this.attr('data-type');

        template.section.set(type);
    }
});
```

Comment: Those are not global variables, therefore are not available through `window`. You should import the collections that you need or have them injected for you when your app is bootstrapped (using dependency injection).

Comment: I already imported the collection - see first code line. But how can I access this collection, if I got the name of it in a variable (`type`)?

Comment: You can create a constant to hold them (e.g, `const collections = {article, ...};`) after importing them and then use `collections[type]` when you need it.

Comment: Could you please put it into the code?

Comment: Can you edit your code to reflect how you actually import, say, 2 collections? It will make it easier for me to make a suggestion. Do you export all of the collection in a single file somewhere?

Comment: updated the code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `window` object will only contain global variables as properties.

However, JavaScript modules are implicitly given their own scope that variables are bound to. And, only the global scope is automatically accessible as a variable.

---

You can use the bracket syntax, `object[property]`, but you'll need to establish a different object containing `article` and `images`.

```
import { article, images } from '../';

const collections = { article, images };

// ...
```

Or, you can import all named exports using [*`import * as name`*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import):

```
import * as collections from '../';

// ...
```

Then, use that object to lookup by `type`:

```
Template.example.helpers({
    list() {
        const type = Template.instance().section.get();
        console.log(type, collections[type]);
        return collections[type].find();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This goes against the zen of Python ("explicit is better than implicit"), but it is reasonable enough here.

You can use the `import * as name from "module-name"` variant to get all of the collections (provided that they are the only thing that is exported from that file, otherwise be explicit).

```
import * as collections from '../index'; //collections includes all of your collections

Template.example.helpers({
    list() {
        const type = Template.instance().section.get();
        return collections[type].find();
    }
});
```

which will get you what you want.